# Sticky navigation bar doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this code to make the navigation bar stick to the top of the page after scrolling:

```
var nav=$('body');
var scrolled=false;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(175<$(window).scrollTop()&&!scrolled){
            nav.addClass('stuck');
            $('.navigation-class').animate({marginTop:80},1000);
            scrolled=true;
        }
        if(175>$(window).scrollTop()&&scrolled){
            $('.navigation-class').animate({marginTop:0},0,function(){nav.removeClass('stuck');$('.navigation-class').removeAttr('style');});
            scrolled=false;
        }
    });
```

The problem is, if the user scrolls the page up and down quickly, and the navigation is STILL animating, it will continue the animation and then suddenly jump into it's designed position, which gives a hiccup effect to the menu.

Try to scroll [this page](http://wallpaperinho.com) quickly to see it in live.

Is it possible to make it run smoothly like other websites?

Thanks are in order.

Comment: Maybe you could choose to listen `touchmove`/`mousewheel` to `scroll` of window. To have the best render effection and avoid wasting resources, `scroll` event will have some questions.`iScroll` choose to listen `touchmove`/`mousewheel` to `scroll`, so it have much better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
After rereading the question, I realized the problem is probably that you're not cancelling the animation when the user scrolls back above 175px.

Presumably you're applying position: float to your nav element? Are you removing float as soon as the user scrolls up?

Try setting the queue option to false (see https://api.jquery.com/animate/), so the animation doesn't wait for the other one to complete.

Maybe you could try getting rid of the JQuery animation and replacing it with CSS transitions?

---

Maybe something like this?

```
var nav=$('body');
var scrolled=false;
var scrollToggle = function(){
        $(window).off('scroll');
        if(175<$(window).scrollTop()&&!scrolled){
            nav.addClass('stuck');
            $('.navigation-class').animate({marginTop:80},1000, function() {
                $(window).on('scroll', scrollToggle);
            );
            scrolled=true;
        }
        else if(175>$(window).scrollTop()&&scrolled){
            $('.navigation-class').animate({marginTop:0},0,function({
                nav.removeClass('stuck');
                $('.navigation-class').removeAttr('style');
                $(window).on('scroll', scrollToggle);
            });
            scrolled=false;
        }
};

$(window).on('scroll', scrollToggle);
```

I have something similar in a WIP myself. I'll post it here only slightly edited, maybe it can be useful to you.

```
var headerFloat = function() {
            //Header
        var pageHeader = $('#pageHeader'), pos = '',
            headerMain = $('#headerMain'), headerMainHeight = '',
            content = $('#content'), contentPadding = '',
            pageTitle = $('h1.currentPage'), pageTitleTop = '';

        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 95) {
            pos = "fixed";
            headerMainHeight = '75px';
            contentPadding = '225px';
            pageTitleTop = '55px';
            contentHeaderTop = '130px';
        }

        //Header
        pageHeader.css('position', pos);
        headerMain.css('height', headerMainHeight);
        content.css('padding-top', contentPadding);
        pageTitle.css({ 'transition': 'all 0s', 'position': pos, 'top': pageTitleTop });
        pageTitle[0].offsetHeight; //force "reflow" of element -- stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/#16575811
        pageTitle.css('transition', '');
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
    /* *** SCROLL -> FLOAT HEADER *** */
    $(window).on("scroll.float", headerFloat);

});
```

Inputting '' (empty string) in the JQuery css function resets it to the original value. You should do that instead of .removeAttr('style');
I would also avoid the scrolled boolean. I think you need it anyway, if scrollTop < 175, you'll never be scrolled, and vice versa.